# SSRS, return rows into a grid layout

Tags: reporting-services

I have a dataset that I need to arrange into a grid on a page (export to pdfs) as a customer report. Each row in my dataset needs to display as a cell. Each page would have roughly 3 records displayed as columns and then 4 rows of records. e.g. a (3x4 grid), being 12 records per page.

Right now I am using a matrix to display my results, but I cannot find how to get my matrix to start a 2nd row after 3 columns are generated.

Is this feasible or should I find a different solution to create these reports?

I was thinking may be if I had row groups to use, but not sure how to create a column that creates a repeating result 3 times then adds 1 to the next 3 results in my query.   111,222,333,444 and that could be my row grouping?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use in a matrix to create a grid of columns from a single cell.

[image]

Add a ROW_NUMBER field to the dataset query and subtract 1 with the ORDER BY using the field to be ordered by.

```
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY DISPLAY_NAME) - 1 AS ROW_NUM
```

Add Calculated Fields to the dataset using the ROW_NUM.

Call the first COLUMN and MOD row_num by 3 to get values or 0 - 2 for the column number:

```
=Fields!ROW_NUM.Value MOD 3
```

Call the second calculated field ROW and get the INT of ROW_NUM divided by 3 to get the row number for the record:

```
=INT(Fields!ROW_NUM.Value / 3)
```

Then the matrix would have the Column grouping (and sorting) based on the COLUMN field and the Row grouping on the ROW field.

[image]

[image]

You could use a parameter as the number of columns (3) to make it easy to change.

Comment: That is great! Thank you so much. I was getting close by creating a formula within the query to calculate row & column #s, but I like your solution better. Now, if I could only figure out why I am getting 3-4 blank pages.

Comment: @mattc try shrinking the colums a little and set the consume whitespace property to true to see if that gets rid of the blank pages.

Comment: @Harry I'm intrigued by your layout as well, because mine is doing just a bunch of rows. How did you structure your fields in that 1 cell?