Converting Infomaker Labels Report to SSRS labels report
I  need to migrate an infomaker/sybase report to SSRS.  Normally this is relatively doable with minimal stress as most reports fall into standard, legal or some other generic form sizes. However, this report i have to rebuild is labels (5160).

However SSRS doesn't seem to have any kind of labels, and the closest thing I could find is 'custom' I'm not sure how to get the report to now print multiple columns of these labels/data elements.

We don't have much choice and definitely have to migrate systems, therefore ssrs is the way we have to go. Open to any suggestions how to accomplish this.
Thank you.

Does this help?  The accepted solution describes how to configure multiple columns per page.

@devlincarnate the link in the answer doesn't work

So, is multiple columns not the right solution for your scenario or is the method described for adding multiple columns not working?

@devlincarnate i haven't tried that - I was hopeful there was a setting, that can link to repeat the label data, more akin to infomaker but better.

I've used a matrix to create something like a sheet of labels and then use regular paper.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68671362/ssrs-return-rows-into-a-grid-layout/68671914#68671914
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68833487/ssrs-report-badges/68837635#68837635
